# How do I add arbitrary HTML to an element in Dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to add arbitrary bits of HTML (like `<span>hello</span>`) to an element. How do I do this in Dart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add arbitrary bits of HTML to an element with `appendHtml('<span>some html</span>')`, like this:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
main() {
  var elem = new DivElement();
  elem.appendHtml('<span>hello</span>');
}
```

The `appendHtml` method will parse the HTML and add the resulting node as the last child of the element.